# App crashing when trying to fetch image from gallery. Please see details

Tags: java, android, uri, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have set up code which allows me to fetch image from gallery and show it in an `ImageView`.
My code worked on Android version 5.0.2, but is crashing on android versions below that.

Here's the error I'm getting: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference                                                                                 at com.humanehelper.humanehelper.PostARequest.getResizedBitmap(PostARequest.java:353)`

Here's `PostARequest.java` file's code:

```
public class PostARequest extends Fragment {

    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView hPic;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public PostARequest() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_a_request, container, false);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pbHeaderProgress);

        hPic = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.h_pic);
        hPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setItems(R.array.choose_profile_pic_choices, mDialogListener);
                android.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    protected DialogInterface.OnClickListener mDialogListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: // Take picture
                    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST);
                    break;
                case 1: // Choose picture
                    Intent choosePhotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    choosePhotoIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(choosePhotoIntent, PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST || requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST) {
                if (data == null) {
                    // display an error
                    return;
                }
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                Bitmap convertedImage = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 200);
                hPic.setImageBitmap(convertedImage);
            }

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 0) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong here.

Please let me know.

Please cooperate on bad format of the question, I'm still in learning phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: change the way you created intent

Comment: it worked, but some images are rotating automatically. How to stop them from rotating?

Comment: You should rotate this images yourself. Read image orientation value from content provider, specifically Images.Media.ORIENTATION field and rotate it correspondingly.

This images are stored rotated. Rotate angle is saved in media database.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the trick ..
Remove this line from your `onactivity` result code And run it .

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

This above line.

```
 @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST || requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST) {
                if (data == null) {
                    // display an error
                    return;
                }
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                Bitmap convertedImage = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 200);
                h.setImageBitmap(convertedImage);
            }

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: this didn't improved anything. still the same error!